# How to use Fetch, CORS headers not working

Tags: javascript, java, frontend, fetch, backend

I am getting this error:

> "No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested
>   resource. Origin '***my origin***' is therefore not allowed access."

Backend:

```
after((request, response) -> {
        response.header("Access-Control-Allow-Origin", "*");
        response.header("Access-Control-Request-Method", "*");
        response.header("Access-Control-Allow-Headers", "*");

        response.type("application/json");
});
```

Frontend:

```
async req() {
  let request_url = ***my url***;

  let init = {
     method: "post",
     body: { **my body content** }
  };

  const res = await fetch( request_url , init );
}
```

Comment: in that case, you're not sending the `access-control-*` headers at all - confirm that all put in `init` is `method` and `body` ... nothing else at all

Comment: `"*"` is **not** a valid value for `Access-Control-Allow-Headers` (not yet) - perhaps that's messing things up - also, `Access-Control-Request-Method` is a **request** header, not a **response** header

Comment: I fixed it adding 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin':'*' in init as header thanks

Comment: whatever `init` is, good - that `after` looked like you were adding the headers "after" something ...

Comment: I just edited the comment, sorry